# Qt TcpSocket::readyRead not triggerd in in a particular situation

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I wrote a simple TCP server in Qt5 whose task can be simplified as:

- listen for connections on a port
- after someone connects to it, read a string from it and then print the string
- close the socket and listen for the next connection

The code of the server is like this:

```
class Server:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    QTcpServer* TcpServer;
    QTcpSocket* TcpSocket;
    void Start();
public slots:
    void OnConnection();
};


void Server::Start()
{
    TcpServer = new QTcpServer();
    TcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9999);
    connect(TcpServer, &QTcpServer::newConnection, this, &Server::OnConnection);
}


void Server::OnConnection()
{
    qDebug() << "connected";
    TcpSocket = TcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    connect(TcpSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, [=]()
    {
      qDebug() << "received:" << TcpSocket->readAll();
      TcpSocket->close();
    });
}
```

Then, I have this code snippet for client:

```
QTcpSocket socket;
socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 9999);
auto x = QString("Some information").toUtf8();
socket.write(x);
socket.close();
```

This code snippet works fine if I run it only in a console application, or run it here in my project:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w; // main window of my application
    w.show();

    QTcpSocket socket;
    socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress::LocalHost, 9999);
    auto x = QString("Some information").toUtf8();
    socket.write(x);
    socket.close();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**Here is the part which makes me confused:**

In the main window, there is a `QPushButton`, its `clicked` signal is connected to a slot, in this slot I will call a function containing the code snippet. The function is mainly dealing with setting up the layout of the main window (I used `QStackedWidget`) , and when the code snippet is executed, it works differently.

From the log of the server I think the socket can connect to the server, however the `QTcpSocket::readyRead` cannot be triggerd, so the server is always waiting for the data, even if all the five lines in the code snippet has been executed.(In the code I provide, the log of the server will only have "connected" without the following data.)

I don't know why the `QTcpSocket::readyRead` of the server cannot be triggerd if I put it in this function. Can somebody explain it?

Thank you for reading my question :-)

Comment: I think you should add http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten method call before closing client socket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write console app it's ok to use your snippet with some modifications, because you don't have to deal with blocking GUI. Just use the following methods:
[waitForConnected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForConnected)
[waitForByttesWritten](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#waitForBytesWritten)

However, if you write GUI one you shold use signals.
Firstly after calling `connectToHost`, wait for [connected](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connected)
signal. Then you can write your data.

After that wait for [bytesWritten](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#bytesWritten) signal and make sure that the `bytes` parameter is equal to value returned by `write` method. When everything is OK you can close the socket.